# normalizer quotient is $\operatorname{GL}_2(p)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, abelian-groups, centralisers

Let $p$ be a prime and let $w$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$. There is an element $e$ of order $p$ in $G=\operatorname{PGL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ where $n=pk$ and
$$e=\left[\left(\begin{matrix}I_k&&&&\\&{wI}_k&&&\\&&{w^2I}_k&&\\&&&\ddots&\\&&&&{w^{p-1}I}_k\\\end{matrix}\right)\right].$$
My focus is on the elementary abelian $p$-subgroups of rank 2 of $G$. Let $E$ be such a group.

Computation shows if all the nontrivial elements of $E$ are conjugate to $e$, then $N_{G}(E) /C_{G}(E) \cong \operatorname{GL}_2(p)$.

I can't see it clearly. I observe that if $E=\langle u,v \rangle = \langle uv,v \rangle = \langle u,uv \rangle$, then a change of basis matrix will be
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&1\\\end{matrix}\right) \, \text{or} \, \left(\begin{matrix}1&1\\0&1\\\end{matrix}\right).$$

These two matrices generate $\operatorname{SL}_2(p)$. Am I arguing along the right lines?

Comment: What you're looking at is representation theory of an extraspecial group $P$ of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$. The central element of order $p$ disappears when you quotient out the scalars, and the automorphism group of $P$ is $p^2GL_2(p)$.

Comment: Presumably your prime $p$ is odd?

Comment: Thank you for your input. Yes, it is odd. I am thinking about the connection between all nontrivials being conjugate to $e$ and the group $P$ or the image of $P$. How are $E$ and the image of $P$ identified？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Look at the group $P$ generated by the following elements of $GL_p(\mathbb{C})$: $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1&&&\\&w&&\\&&\ddots&\\&&&w^{p-1}\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}&1&&\\&&1&\\&&&\ddots\\1&&&&\end{smallmatrix}\right)$. Then $P$ is an extraspecial group of order $p^3$ and exponent $p$. Its image in $PGL_p(\mathbb{C})$ is elementary abelian $E$ of order $p^2$, and the normaliser modulo centraliser is $SL_2(p)$, acting as the group of all automorphisms of determinant one of $E$. There are $p-1$ representations like this, permuted by $GL_2(p)$; in other words, related by automorphisms of $E$. You can distinguish between these $p-1$ representations by the scalar representing a non-identity central element.

You can't mix different ones of these representations if the central element of $P$ has to act as a scalar on the entire space. So there are only two possibilities: Either your representation consists of $k$ copies of one of the $p-1$ representations above, in which case the normaliser modulo centraliser is $SL_2(p)$; or $k$ is divisible by $p$, and your representation is a direct sum of $p/k$ copies of the regular representation of the elementary abelian $E$, in which case the normaliser modulo centraliser is $GL_2(p)$.

**Note** I have edited this answer several times, for the sake of both correctness and readability. Apologies for any confusion caused.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to write "thank you for all your input".

Comment: You also keep accepting and unaccepting my answer, which is a little annoying.

Comment: Sorry about that...

Comment: I seem to have grasped your answer, thank you! Just one question on the last sentence. I'm being stupid here.  Why in the regular representation case, $N/C$ is the full automorphism group? And you mean $k/p$ copies of the regular reps, right? Thank you!

Comment: I suppose my question is: for the 2nd possibility, why this particular representation where all the nontrivial elts are conjugate to $e$ gives the $N/C$ structure?

Comment: Because there are other reps (where not every nontrivial elt is conjugate to $e$) which don't give this $N/C$ structure.

Comment: Okay, let me express this in terms of character theory. Your condition implies that the trace of all non-identity elements of $E$ is zero. So the inner products of your character with all one dimrensional irreducibles are equal. So the number of copies of each is the same. It follows that all automorphisms of $E$ take this to an isomorphic representation. The isomorphism then gives the required element of the normaliser to effect this automorphism of $E$. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I've got it. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Sorry to trouble with a related question. Could I also conclude that the conjugacy class in $G$ to which $E$ belongs is unique because it is from the regular representation?